# relation bw group_concated columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know my question is kind of weird but i will try to make it as clear as possible.

```
products_table
        ID | code | product_variants_id | product_name | variants     | variants_value   
        1  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | color        | blue
        2  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | temperature  | cold
        3  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | weight       | 0.5
        4  |     2|  123453             | ad wrap      | color        | green
        5  |     2|  123453             | ad wrap      | weight       | 1
```

This is what my final product table looks like , now to display the products , this is what i did.

```
SELECT xx.code, GROUP_CONCAT(xx.variants) AS variants,
        GROUP_CONCAT(xx.variants_value) AS variants_value , 
        xx.product_name, xx.product_variants_id 
FROM products_table xx 
GROUP BY xx.product_variants_id
```

After this query my table looks something like this

```
       code | product_variants_id   | product_name | variants                | variants_value   
         1  |   123451              | beer cake    | color,temperature,weight| blue,cold,0.5
         2  |   123453              | ad wrap      | color,weight            | green,1
```

Now i can simply run  through this table and get products one by one and display it's variants.

My real question, is there any way to link these concatenated results that i just obtained?

For example:
 at the server side i can get the variant `color` , how can i get the corresponding value of the `color`?

What would be my approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate the variant and corresponding values together first, then do the `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT xx.code, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(xx.variants,':',xx.variants_value)) AS variants_and_values, xx.product_name, xx.product_variants_id
FROM products_table xx
GROUP BY xx.product_variants_id, xx.product_name, xx.code
```

Comment: That's creative.I'm really impressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example get the result data and iterate over it.

PHP implementation:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    $data[$key]['variants'] = explode(',', $item['variants']);
    $data[$key]['variants_value'] = explode(',', $item['variants_value']);
}
```

so you will have `$data[$key]['variants'][0]` holding color and `$data[$key]['variants_value'][0]` holding its value

Comment: isn't there any sql solution?

Comment: The OP has not indicated what programming language is used for the application.